# Can Prädikat be in an infinitive form?

Tags: verb

I was not able to find whether or not Infinitivkonstruktionen are considered to be a Prädikat.

For example:

> Ich lerne Deutsch, um in Deutschland studieren zu können.

I suppose this sentence has only one Prädikat, because that should be in a finite verb form, right?

And what about these types of sentences:

> Ich versuche, das Tor zu treffen.

> In einem neben der Kommode stehenden Schirmständer steht ein Schirm.

Again, I suppose all of these examples have only one Prädikat, but I just cannot verify it anywhere.

Danke!

Answer (score 1):

It may be helpful to note that the common parts of a German sentence, like the Prädikat or the Subjekt, don't have to consist of one word only. A Prädikat *has* to contain a finite verb form, but it can contain additional elements, too.

For example, in

> Ich *lese* ein Buch.

the Prädikat happens to be just the word "lese". But in

> Ich *möchte* ein Buch *lesen*.

the Prädikat is actually "möchte... lesen" and contains multiple parts.

Another example would be

> Gestern *hat* niemand den Hund *spazieren geführt*.

where the Prädikat is "hat... spazieren geführt".

Infinite verbs are among the range of elements that can appear in a Prädikat. For example

> Ich *glaube zu träumen*.

where the whole of "glaube zu träumen" is the Prädikat.

With regard to your examples

> Ich lerne Deutsch, um in Deutschland studieren zu können.

isn't actually *one* sentence, but two - or rather, a main clause and a subclause. Each of those has a Prädikat:

> Ich *lerne* Deutsch, um in Deutschland *studieren zu können*.

The situation is similar with

> Ich *versuche*, das Tor zu *treffen*.

A main clause with its Prädikat, and a sub clause with its Prädikat.

Your third example actually is only one sentence, with one Prädikat

> In einem neben der Kommode stehenden Schirmständer *steht* ein Schirm.

Here, the "stehenden" is part of an extension of "Schirmständer" and not a Prädikat, or part of one. You *could* rephrase the sentence similar to above and have two Prädikate, one per clause

> In einem Schirmständer, der neben der Kommode *steht*, *steht* ein Schirm.

Comment: An interesting example would be a sentence with an enumeration of finite verbs, like "Sie essen, trinken und lachen". Would that be considered three Prädikate in the same sentence? Another form of one Prädikat with multiple parts? Or a shortened form of three separate sentences?

Comment: Thank you so much, now I finally understand!

Comment: Strictly speaking, *um in Deutschland studieren zu können* is not a subclause (*Nebensatz*) but an infinitive group (*Infinitivgruppe*).

Comment: The subject-predicate model divides everything into either subject or predicate, where the predicate includes the verb and anything else that's not in the subject phrase. I don't think this realistic for German though; in fact there are grammatical sentences in German which don't have a subject. I prefer to use predicate to mean the object of a copulative verb (*sein*, *werden*, etc.), which can be nouns, adjectives, or certain adverbs and prepositional phrases. This is more properly a "predicative expression", but it seems silly not to simply call it a "predicate" if the word is available.